# Information contained in multiple logs separated by other logs in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, multiline, elastic-stack

This is being a little bit tricky for me.
I need to put together data that is separated into two logs. The multiline has helped me before but now the logs are separated by 3-4 logs not related to the information I want to get, is not consistent and it has no patterns to really match the beginning or the end. For example:

```
[0m[[32msuccess[0m] [0mTotal time: 367 s, completed 2016-09-20 15:00:06[0m    
[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0m[32mAll tests passed.[0m[0m
[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mPassed: Total 96, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 96[0m
```

Whenever I get the line Passed:Total 96... Then take the Total time: 367s.

The situation here is that Jenkins is creating multiples logs with the following line:

```
[0m[[32msuccess[0m] [0mTotal time: 367 s, completed 2016-09-20 15:00:06[0m
```

but I've been told we are only interested whenever is created after the other line. I was expecting one line after the other:

```
[0m[[32msuccess[0m] [0mTotal time: 367 s, completed 2016-09-20 15:00:06[0m    
[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mPassed: Total 96, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 96[0m
```

But whenever it has errors or  fails, we get in the console the error messages and **after** the total time that took to complete.
Has someone managed to solve this kind of situation previously?

Comment: If you are using the multiline filter, you can drop the uninteresting lines before doing the multiline. If you are using the codec, you can use two logstash, the first one dropping the uninteresting lines and sending the remaining lines to the second one with the multiline codec on input.

Comment: Or you can use sthg else than Logstash, since it looks like it's not the right tool for the job you are trying to do

Comment: Which tools could you recommend?
I was thinking the same about dropping but the lines vary between one and the other so I wouldn't know what to drop exactly.

Comment: i was thinking of perhaps a report integrated to Jenkins (but I don't know if that exists) or just parsing the whole file with regex and just retrieving the relevant information rather than trying to group lines together in Logstash.

Comment: Would a conditional filter not help? if "Passed: Total" in [message] { grok { <filter>} }